# EMail sharing by MFMailComposeViewController in objective c not work properly for IOS 9.0. ToRecipients and send option is not worked

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am trying to open email composure in iOS 9 and send option is not working. I have downloaded some project they also have the same problem with ios 9.

I have declared `globalMailComposer` in app delegate .h and this code is in app delegate .m file in a alert buton

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
{

    globalMailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    self.globalMailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    NSString *emailTitle = @"Test Email";
    NSString *messageBody = @"iOS programming is so fun!";
    NSArray *toRecipents:    [NSArrayarrayWithObjects:@"support@appcoda.com",nil];
    [globalMailComposer setSubject:emailTitle];
    [globalMailComposer setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:NO];
    [globalMailComposer setToRecipients:toRecipents];
    [self.window.rootViewControllerpresentViewController:globalMailComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
}


- (void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Mail cancelled");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"Mail saved");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Mail sent");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Mail sent failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    [self.window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES  completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: what the error u faced

Comment: check once in device

Comment: Thanks for support me.. when I run on simulator the error i faced: messageBody,toRecipents field is empty but emailTitle field shows and app crashed  error:  viewServiceDidTerminateWithError: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={Message=Service Connection Interrupted} with message mail canceled. But when run on device nothing shows.

Comment: when i  use below code then on device the pop up shows: No Mail account please setup a mail account in order to send mail.  -       (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
       [self cycleTheGlobalMailComposer];
        return YES;
    }
     -(void)cycleTheGlobalMailComposer
    {
    
    self.globalMailComposer = nil;
    self.globalMailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    }

Comment: once set up the email in your device and check this once

Comment: I have already done this.but same issue is faced. Although I have faced this problem every email shaing app that was downloded from aapcoda and other site.

Comment: Thanku Mr. Anbu.Karthik I was trying to login with Safari thats why I was facing the problem. Now it is solved

Comment: happy to hear, do well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You cannot send mails from within the simulator. Always test this on a real device.
2. Try this code on your device which works perfectly fine for me:

**AppDelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@import MessageUI;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, strong) MFMailComposeViewController *globalMailComposer;

@end
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate () <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        self.globalMailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        self.globalMailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        NSString *emailTitle = @"Test Email";
        NSString *messageBody = @"iOS programming is so fun!";
        [self.globalMailComposer setSubject:emailTitle];
        [self.globalMailComposer setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:NO];
        [self.globalMailComposer setToRecipients:@[@"support@appcoda.com"]];
        [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:self.globalMailComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

    return YES;
}

- (void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Mail cancelled");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"Mail saved");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Mail sent");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Mail sent failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    [self.window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES  completion:NULL];
}

@end
```

3. If it's still not working make sure you have set up the mail account on your device correctly.It should appear in your Settings under Mail-Accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it does not work on simulator, but works well on any of the device.
Have you checked it on a device?

Comment: Thanks for support. I run on device nothing shows. and the error i faced on simulator is: messageBody,toRecipents field is empty but emailTitle field shows and app crashed error: viewServiceDidTerminateWithError: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={Message=Service Connection Interrupted} with message mail canceled.

Comment: Yes, it really does, I do not know why, maybe it is a bug that Apple does.

Comment: So my solution is that run any of the test of MFMailComposeViewController on real device instead of simulator, and it works well for me.